# How to print an object's representation using the string format function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm creating a Money class, and I'd like to pass the object directly to the string format() function and get the money representation with 2 decimals and the currency symbol.

What method should I override to print with the string format function? Overriding **str** and **repr** did not work.

```
from decimal import Decimal


class Money(Decimal):
    def __str__(self):
        return "$" + format(self, ',.2f')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "$" + format(self, ',.2f')

m = Money("123.44")
print(m) # $123.44. Good.
m        # $123.44. Good.
print("Amount: {0}".format(m)) # 123.44. Bad. I wanted $123.44
print(f"Amount: {m}") # 123.44. Bad. I wanted $123.44
```

Comment: If you want to force repr you can use `f'{m!r}'`.

Comment: By the way, you probably don't actually want to override `repr` this way. Normally, a `repr` either looks like (a) source code to recreate the object (e.g., `Money("123.44")`), or (b) something in angle brackets that cannot be interpreted as anything but a repr (like `<Money value=Decimal('123.44')>`).

Comment: @PaulPanzer That's not what he's asking for.

Comment: @abarnert well, it's a comment, not an answer ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can give your class a [`__format__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__); in this case just call overridden version:

```
def __format__(self, spec):
    spec = spec or ',.2f'  # set a default spec when not explicitly given
    return '$' + super().__format__(spec)
```

From the linked documentation:

> Called by the `format()` built-in function, and by extension, evaluation of formatted string literals and the `str.format()` method, to produce a “formatted” string representation of an object. The `format_spec` argument is a string that contains a description of the formatting options desired. The interpretation of the `format_spec` argument is up to the type implementing `__format__()`, however most classes will either delegate formatting to one of the built-in types, or use a similar formatting option syntax.

You'll want to drop your `__str__` and `__repr__` implementations now, or at least not add another `'$'` on top of the one `__format__` now adds (which `format(self, ...)` will trigger).

Demo:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> class Money(Decimal):
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...         spec = spec or ',.2f'  # set a default spec when not explicitly given
...         return '$' + super().__format__(spec)
...
>>> m = Money("123.44")
>>> print("Amount: {0}".format(m))
Amount: $123.44
>>> print(f"Amount: {m}")
Amount: $123.44
```

Comment: He will obviously need to change his `__str__` and `__repr__` methods to not add an extra `$` on top of `format(self)` then.